# Where store folder signed, requests, yaml in puppet 6

Tags: puppet

I try migrate cluster puppet 3 community edition to cluster puppet 6 community edition. I dont use puppet db.

I sync custom folder on cluster puppet 6:

```
/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/signed
/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/requests
/var/lib/puppet/yaml
```

Where store folder signed, requests, yaml  in puppet 6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default locations for what you are looking for in Puppet 6 are, respectively,

```
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca/signed
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca/requests
/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/yaml
```

It sounds like you may be trying to avoid re-registering all your nodes with the new master, but Puppet 3 to Puppet 6 is a *huge* upgrade.  Puppet has implemented some changes to its certificate handling in between, and you might find that Puppet 6 does not accept the certs signed by your Puppet 3 CA.  One thing to consider would be to install the P6 agents alongside the P3 agents, and to use P3 to make the P6 agents register with the P6 master.  I did something similar with a 0.24 to 5.0 upgrade.